# Reflect Copying process with progress bar and percentage

Tags: java, server, copy, progress, zk

I am using `ZK freamework`.

I am preparing a project which copies Data from `one server` and pastes Data to another server. Till end project is working fine and even this is doing the work as per my expectations. I want to show a process bar with the percentage of data copying process. I am using `ZK framework`, Java Spring, and Mysql.

My requirement is to show the `percentage of copying done and a progress bar` in `zk Framework`. please help me through this.

Thanks in advance.

```
for(long j=1;j<=rowCount;j++){          
    sum = sum + j/rowCount;
    if(j==rowCount){                
    sum=100;
}   
progressMeter.setValue(sum);            
countLabel.setValue((rowCount-1)+" Rows are inserted");
BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, countLabel, "_value");
```

Comment: @MouseEvent Thanks for the reply. I am quite new to such tasks. Can you please provide me some links for references.

Answer (score 0):

In ZK framework you need to use Progressmeter component. 
In your example.zul you need to add the following code :

```
 <progressmeter id="uploadProgress" value="0" width="300px" />
```

And in your project class you need to update value of this component.

```
    public class ProgressmeterController extends SelectorComposer<Hlayout> {
    @Wire
    private Progressmeter uploadProgress;

    @Wire
    private Timer timer;

    @Listen("onTimer = #timer")
    public void fetchingSimulatorTimer() {
        //calculate completed percent
        uploadProgress.setValue(percent);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did the same way. but the problem is progress bar is not slowly updating. suddenly it takes 100% after completing the task

Comment: comment on your code  sum = sum + 100/rowCount;  I think you need to user something like this sum +=  j / rowCount;

Comment: @VijayKarchi if you directly goes to 100% then your long operation is in 1 execution done. You need to move the operation to a separate thread.  With the timer tick, only search your progress and update it.

Comment: @chillworld Thanks, can you please provide code snippet

Comment: @VijayKarchi see mine answer below, use that mechanism and his code to achieve your goal

Answer (score 0):

Beside mine comment,
I would like to point you to a small talk of Robert Wenzel.

He has written some code to simplify long operations and make the updating of the screen easier.

https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2015/January/Simplify_Long_Operation_Handlings

Check it out and maybe you could use it in your application.